# ruby - need help understanding this inject

Tags: ruby, inject

I'd like to understand how the following code works:

```
def url
  @url ||= {
    "basename" => self.basename,
    "output_ext" => self.output_ext,
  }.inject("/:basename/") { |result, token|
    result.gsub(/:#{token.first}/, token.last)
  }.gsub(/\/\//, "/")
end
```

I know what it does; somehow it returns the url corresponding to a file located o a dir on a server. So it returns strings similar to this: `/path/to/my/file.html`

I understand that if `@url` already has a value, it will be returned and the right `||=` will be discarded. I also understand that this begins creating a hash of two elements.

I also think I understand the last gsub; it replaces backslashes by slashes (to cope with windows servers, I guess).

What amazes me is the `inject` part. I'm not able to understand it. I have used `inject` before, but this one is too much for me. I don't see how this be done with an `each`, since I don't understand what it does.

I modified the original function slightly for this question; the original comes from [this jekyll file](http://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/blob/master/lib/jekyll/page.rb#L57).

Cheers!

Comment: "the last gsub; it replaces backslashes by slashes" -- no, it looks to me like it replaces double slashes with slashes.

Comment: You are right - thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foo.inject(bar) {|result, x| f(result,x) }
```

Can always be written as:

```
result = bar
foo.each {|x| result = f(result, x)}
result
```

So for your case, the version with each would look like this:

```
result = "/:basename/"
{
  "basename" => self.basename,
  "output_ext" => self.output_ext,
}.each {|token|
  result = result.gsub(/:#{token.first}/, token.last)
}
result
```

Meaning: for all key-value-pairs in the hash, each occurrence of the key in the `"/:basename/"` is replaced with the value.

Comment: Ohh. So it basically replaces ':basename' by its real value. I understand now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps splitting the code and tweaking a little helps

```
options = { "basename" => self.basename, "output_ext" => self.output_ext }

options.inject("/:basename") do |result, key_and_kalue|  
  # Iterating over the hash yields an array of two elements, which I called key_and_value

  result.gsub(":#{key_and_value[0]}", key_and_value[1])
end.gsub!(//\/\/, '/')
```

Basically, the inject code is iterating over all your `options` and replacing for the actual value wherever it sees a ":key"